# Javascript style.display not working with form

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are variations of this question on other threads, but none seem to help me with my answer. Hopefully it is quite a simple one... What am I doing wrong?

I have an option field, and when the user selects "Between" as a drop-down option, I want it to add another input box - in this case called 'AdditionalThreshold'.

```js
function toggleMe(a) {
  var e=document.getElementByName("AdditionalThreshold");
  if(e.style.display=="none"){
    e.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <select name="ThresholdType">
    <option value="GreaterThan">Greater than or Equal to</option>
    <option value="Between" onClick="toggleMe('BetweenField')">Between</option>
    <option value="LessThan">Less than</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input name="Threshold" type="text" size="4" />
  <input name="AdditionalThreshold" type="text" id="BetweenField" size="4" style="display:none;">
</td>
```

I am quite the novice at this so forgive my coding, but any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In what way does this not work the way you want it to?

Comment: There in an invisible (`display: none` by default) box that he wants to turn visible when the 'Between' option is selected from a dropdown, and turn invisible when another option is selected.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yep, I understand that. The OP hasn't said how his current code isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('ThresholdType').addEventListener("change", function(){
 var visibility = (this.value === 'Between')?"block":"none";
    console.log(this.value);
    document.getElementsByName('AdditionalThreshold')[0].style.display = visibility;
})
```

```html
<select id="ThresholdType">
        <option value="GreaterThan">Greater than or Equal to</option>
        <option value="Between">Between</option>
        <option value="LessThan">Less than</option>
    </select>
    <input id="Threshold" type="text" size="4" />
    <input name="AdditionalThreshold" type="text" id="BetweenField" size="4" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Thanks @scraaappy. This is brilliant and exactly what I am after. Thanks everyone for your support - it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to use:

```
document.getElementsByName("AdditionalThreshold")
```

in which case returns an array-like structure called a NodeList. 
So you would want to do

```
document.getElementsByName("AdditionalThreshold")[0];
```

to select the first one. (assuming thats the one you want)

Comment: Technically [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) doesn't return an array, but a live [`NodeList` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Comment: @qxz Thats correct. I fixed it. Its array-like but you don't have everything at your disposal that a regular array does.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="ThresholdType">
    <option value="GreaterThan">Greater than or Equal to</option>
    <option value="Between">Between</option>
    <option value="LessThan">Less than</option>
</select>
<input name="Threshold" type="text" size="4" />
<input name="AdditionalThreshold" type="text" id="BetweenField" size="4" class="hide">

<script>
function toggleBetween(event) {
    if(event.target.value.toLowerCase() === 'between') {
      document.querySelector('#BetweenField').classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#BetweenField').classList.add('hide');
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('select[name="ThresholdType"]').addEventListener('change', toggleBetween, false);
})
</script>

<style>
.hide {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

http://jsbin.com/pigocekava/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks @Joe. This worked really well as well. Your support is much appreciated, thanks.